# C# String greater than or equal code string

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

I'm trying to get my code working my comparing if a string is bigger or less than 10, but it doesn't work correctly. It writes 10 or more even if the value is less than 10.

```
int result = string1.CompareTo("10");
if (result < 0)
{
     Console.WriteLine("less than 10");
}
else if (result >= 0)
{
     Console.WriteLine("10 or more");
}
```

Comment: You mean `string` or `string.Length`?

Answer (score 25):

A string is not a number, so you're comparing lexicographically(from left to right). [`String.CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w.aspx) is used for ordering, but note that `"10"` is "lower" than `"2"` since the char `1` is already *lower* than the char `2`.

I assume what you want want is to convert it to an `int`:

```
int i1 = int.Parse(string1);
if (i1 < 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("less than 10");
}
else if (i1 >= 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("10 or more");
}
```

Note that you should use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) if `string1` could have an invalid format. On that way you prevent an exception at `int.Parse`, e.g.:

```
int i1;
if(!int.TryParse(string1, out i1))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please provide a valid integer!");
}
else
{
    // code like above, i1 is the parsed int-value now
}
```

---

However, if you instead want to check if a string is *longer* or *shorter* than 10 characters, you have to use it's [`Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx) property:

```
if (string1.Length < 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("less than 10");
}
else if (string1.Length >= 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("10 or more");
}
```

Comment: The solution is correct, of course. The way `CompareTo` works with strings is complex, and it uses a culture-aware comparison, and it is not simple lexicographical ordering in all cases. For example, in many .NET cultures, a dash `-` will be ignored. So `"-12".CompareTo("10")` is like `"12".CompareTo("10")`, it gives a positive integer (`1`). And `"-1".CompareTo("10")` like `"1".CompareTo("10")` is negative (`-1`). There _might_ be .NET cultures where this is different, though I doubt it.

Comment: `else if...` seemes a bit redundant :)

Comment: I think I would make it a tryparse in case it is not a number.  Then keep the else if and have an else for this exception.

Comment: @Silvermind: Yes, but i wanted to change only the relevant part of OP's code. Also, he might want to add multiple conditions later.

Comment: @JustinHarvey: In general it's good when people suggest how to improve code.  But an answer should concentrate on the essentials. Otherwise you add too much noise and OP doesnt know what he actually needs to change or what was the issue at all. If he comes back with a `FormatException` we can help with the `int.TryParse` method.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I am not sure I agree.  I think SO is a good resource of the best answers possible to peoples questions.  I think the aim should be to advise people of the best way of doing things.

Comment: @JustinHarvey: Edited my answer. However, i don't agree that you always have to add a hodgepodge  of good-practises if they are not related to the issue. Then i create a copy/paste library with the best-of advices on-topic and add them to every answer.