# Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework in C# and my code is

```
var result = ef.services.Where(entry => entry.tarikhservice >= textBoxX1.Text
                                     && entry.tarikhservice <= textBoxX2.Text).ToList();
```

which gives me this error:

> Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

How to compare two string and fix the error?

Comment: You should use `CompareTo`. that allows  you to specify culture/

Comment: Could you please explain how semantically you decide if one string is greater than another?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - Count the number of votes its received :)

Comment: "How to compare to string" depends on what you're comparing and how you want them to be compared. Are they actually numbers? Sequential string labels? Be more clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity framework strings using greater than operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380985/entity-framework-strings-using-greater-than-operator)

Comment: Assuming that you are trying to compare two dates read from a textbox, you should either use DatePicker instead of TextBox or use converted values as result = ef.services.Where(entry => DateTime.Parse(entry.tarikhservice) >= DateTime.Parse(textBoxX1.Text) && DateTime.Parse(entry.tarikhservice) <= DateTime.Parse(textBoxX2.Text)).ToList(); Please bear in mind that this coe is not safe and might raise Exception if the values are not set or properly set.

Answer (score 25):

When you compare numbers, say 1 and 2, it is clear which one is greater. However, when you compare strings, which one is considered greater: "2" or "11"? "foo" or "f"? Answer: it depends on context. For example if you sort them lexicographically, you get "2" and "f". If you want the natural sort, you would get "2" before "11".

I presume for that reason, relative operators (>, >=, <, <=) are not overloaded for string (which IMHO is a good decision).

Your option is to either write your custom logic to compare strings, or use a framework-provided lexicographical comparison. The code would be (if I got the numbers right):

```
var result = ef.services.Where(entry => 
        string.Compare(entry.tarikhservice, textBoxX1.Text) >= 0
     && string.Compare(entry.tarikhservice, textBoxX2.Text) <= 0
   .ToList()
```

To make code work regardless of culture (you should!), provide a StringComparison as last parameter to string.compare:

```
string.Compare(entry.tarikhservice, textBoxX1.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Of course we expect "2" and "f". Must one use the non intuitive `string.Compare` function?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I agree with the rationale given in the current answers for not implementing the comparison operators in `String`. In fact, I submit that implementing them using `String.Compare` would be just as consistent as the current equality operator implementation using `String.Equals`.

I have a different theory. If you examine the [Best Practices for Using Strings in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings) you will note the following recommendation:

> The String class lets you test for equality by calling either the
>   static or instance Equals method overloads, or by using the static
>   equality operator. The overloads and operator use ordinal comparison
>   by default. However, we still recommend that you call an overload that
>   explicitly specifies the StringComparison type even if you want to
>   perform an ordinal comparison

Note that they couldn't enforce this recommendation even if they wanted to - even if they didn't override the `==` operator in `String`, you could still do  `str1 == str2`. Heck, you could compare an integer to a string using the equality operator if you really wanted to (`obj i = 1`). This is because `==` translates into reference equality when not overridden specifically for the operand types.

The BCL designers realized this and decided they would be better off implementing a comparison operator that works as expected *most* of the time, rather than delegate the comparison to reference equality, which would be a really bad idea considering [string interning](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/09/28/string-interning-and-string-empty/) and [Unicode equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence).

Now, back to comparison operators. The same pitfalls with string equality apply, but the BCL designers have an easier time here. By simply not implementing these operators, the compiler does their job for them and, as we can see in this question, prevents devs from even trying to do things like `str1 >= str2`.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite reasonable that you take. *Two strings can be equal or not equal*. Nothing less nothing more. The greater and the less operator makes sense, when you compare numbers, or if you compare objects for which you have overloaded this operators.

As it is stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132435/c-sharp-string-greater-than-or-equal-code-string),

> A string is not a number, so you're comparing lexicographically.
>   String.CompareTo is used for ordering.

Comment: And SQL generally allows using `<` and `>` in string comparison (meaning a different thing that the OP probably expects, granted)

Comment: PS: I haven't downvoted since I still feel the answer is "somehow" correct. As it turns out, @ya23's answer is just more spot-on (saying basically the same)